# Reading and storing cyrillic in variables

Tags: vbscript, cyrillic

I am trying to read cyrillic values separated by ; from a file, scan every line for match in the first value and assign the following values to variables.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim objStream, strData, splitted
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("C:\temp\textfile.txt")
strData = objStream.ReadText()
MsgBox strData
splitted = split(strData, ";")
```

`textfile.txt` contains something like this:

```
Име;Адрес;Телефон;
Име2;Адрес2;Телефон2;
```

I will have a variable like this:

```
searchFor = "Име"
```

and the script must assign `Адрес` and `Телефон` to variables.

Basically, I need to search for the name(`Име` or `Име2`) in every line from the `textfile` and then assign the second and the third values of that line to variables.

Currently `strData` gets the data but it's stored as a string that I cannot manipulate or don't know how.

Comment: Works for me, provided the content of `textfile.txt` is actually UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I still cannot split it, always get type mismatch no matter of all the versions of UTF-8 that i tried...

Comment: Please show the exact error you're getting and the code that raises it.

Comment: Wow, i found my mistake , i was calling with MsgBox only splitted , without any positions (e.g. splitted(0)).How can i now search with another variable (e.g. Search="Име" the first word of every line and if a match to convert the line to array(not the whole stdData) and then to assign the second and the third values to different variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the text at newlines, then split each line at semicolons, then check if the first field matches your search value. Example:

```
searchFor = "Име"
For Each line In Split(strData, vbNewLine)
  fields = split(line, ";")
  If fields(0) = searchFor Then
    varA = fields(1)
    varB = fields(2)
  End If
Next
```

Note that you *must* save the script in Unicode format, lest your search string be botched.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete final working script (Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers!)

```
Dim objStream, strData, fields
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile("C:\temp\textfile.txt")
strData = objStream.ReadText()
MsgBox strData
searchFor = "Име"
MsgBox searchFor
For Each line In Split(strData, vbNewLine)
  fields = Split(line, ";")
  If fields(0) = searchFor Then
    varA = fields(1)
    varB = fields(2)
  End If
Next
```